# Resource container of org.eclipse.core.resources is not returning any value in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resourcebundle

I have a project in eclipse workspace. When my program runs,it puts output inside some directory(which might not exist initially) inside the project.I need to refresh this directory so that output is visible in eclipse workspace.

Following code is used for the same.

```
IContainer[] OutputDir = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findContainersForLocationURI(path.toUri())
for (IContainer OpFolder : OutputDir) {
                try {

                        OpFolder.refreshLocal(IProject.DEPTH_INFINITE,new NullProgressMonitor());

                } catch (CoreException e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

For a path which contains parent and child folder name as same it is not working

For ex: Lets say 
project root path : D:/casdev/myProject

output path : D:/casdev/myProject/out/ct/CT/report

In this case it is not refreshing as findContainersForLocationURI() returning empty containers

If output path : D:/casdev/myProject/out/CT/Proj/report
then it works fine.

When I checked the implementation of findContainersForLocationURI() somewhere it returns this path as filtered path. May be that is because it has ct/CT in the path.

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you actually passing to `findContainersForLocationURI()`? Most of `org.eclipse.core.resources` uses **locations** for the file system and **paths** to mean within the workspace's own logical structure.

Comment: I am passing a java.net.URI. I construct a Path object with absolute path and then using toUri() method to get URI.